# Is there an easier way to rewrite SQL Server queries for PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

In particular, I'm looking for a way to more easily rewrite my like queries without having to use the "lower" function each time.

In SQL Server, my query would look like this:

```
WHERE (FIELD LIKE '%Foot%Locker%' or FIELD LIKE '%Foot%Action%' or FIELD LIKE '%Champs%')
```

In PostgreSQL, I must rewrite each query as such (if I want my query to capture both Foot Locker AND foot locker and any other caps driven permutation):

```
WHERE (lower(FIELD) LIKE lower('%foot%locker%') or lower(FIELD) LIKE lower('%foot%action%') or lower(FIELD) LIKE lower('%champs%')
```

This, of course, is very annoying.  I have to rewrite 100s of queries.  Is there an easy workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Postgres has just what you are looking for `ilike`:

> The key word `ILIKE` can be used instead of `LIKE` to make the match
>   case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the
>   SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

(Documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).)

So, you can do something like:

```
WHERE (field ILIKE '%foot%locker%' or FIELD ILIKE '%foot%action%' or FIELD) ILIKE '%champs%'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
WHERE lower(field) ~ '(foot.*locker)|(foot.*action)|champ'
```

Comment: you actually don't need the `lower()` if you use `~*` instead of `~`